# Adding Active Directory resource groups to a checkedlistbox in Powershell Studio

Tags: powershell, user-interface, active-directory

Right now I have successfully queried active directory to get a list of all of the resource groups avaiable as such:

```
$AD_ResourceGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Resource Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Paper Transport,DC=papertransport,DC=com"
```

This is stored in the `$AD_ResourceGroups` variable. I am then attempting to add that list of the resource groups into the checklist itself like such:

```
$chklistGroups.Items.Add($AD_ResourceGroups,'Unchecked')
```

When I launch the GUI, the only thing that shows up in the checkedlistbox is one single entry: `Object[]Array`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are adding 1 thing to the list, an array. What you want to do is iterate through the array, and add each item to the list.

```
$AD_ResourceGroups | ForEach-Object { $chklistGroups.Items.Add($_,'Unchecked') }
```

**Edit:** Use Jason Snell's answer, it's better. I forgot about the AddRange method.

Answer (score 4):

`Add` is used to add a single item. If you're using an array you need to use `AddRange` which will add the array as single items to your checklistbox.